# Do DDR2 chips and controllers have on-die termination?

Tags: intel-fpga, ddr2, sdram, termination

I am going to try to interface a low-speed 8-bit DDR2 chip with an FPGA, and I've got some questions crucial to make it work:

Is that correct that there is on-die termination on both DDR2 memory and controllers (an Altera Cyclone 3 FPGA in my case), so no additional termination resistors are required?

Comment: A DDR2 Chip - As in a Dram IC, or a DDR *Card*, as in the kind of memory module you see in a desktop computer (which are not, and will never really be "chips", even if some uneducated people like to call them so)?

Comment: Single DDR2 IC. Interfacing to whole DIMM is pretty hardcore for beginners :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all DDR2 chips have it on-board. It is a required part of the standard.

Comment: DDR2 is controlled by JEDEC, which has gratis standards, right?  What is the number of the relevant standard?

Comment: I don't have the standard; check Micron's web site for DDR2 data sheets and application notes.

Comment: JESD79-2F is the JEDEC standard number for DDR2. The chips must have an ODT pin which enables/disables on-board termination.

Comment: Also, you can control the strength: infinite-ohms, 75-ohms, and 150-ohms are required.  Some chips support 50-ohms too.